# biblatex-chicago: sentence-case for journal articles

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'd like to use the sentence case (without editing the bib file!) for journal articles with biblatex-chicago but don't know how.  So far, `\MakeSentenceCase*` looks promising to me, but it fails to change the cases for me.  I use lualatex + biber on texlive 2020 on macOS Big Sur. A self-contained example is below.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{tmp-refs.bib}
@article{paper:Title-Case,
  title = {Title-Cased Title {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author = {Author Aaa and Author Bbb},
  year = {1986},
  volume = {16},
  pages = {1929-1943},
  journal = {Journal of Something}
}
@article{paper:Sentence-case,
  title = {Sentence-cased title {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author = {Author Ccc and Author Ddd},
  year = {1987},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {1943-1949},
  journal = {Journal of Something Else}
}
@book{book:Title-Case,
  title = {Title-Cased Book Title {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author = {Author Eee},
  year = {1988},
  pages = {123},
  publisher = {A Good Publisher}
}
@book{book:Sentence-case,
  title = {Sentence-cased book {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author = {Author Fff},
  year = {1989},
  pages = {567},
  publisher = {Another Good Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{tmp-refs}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase:title}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
\begin{document}
\autocite{paper:Title-Case}
\autocite{paper:Sentence-case}
\autocite{book:Title-Case}
\autocite{book:Sentence-case}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the standard `biblatex` styles, `biblatex-chicago` does not use the `titlecase` field format. So we need to modify the relevant bibmacro(s) to switch from the `noformat` field format to `titlecase`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{mag+news+title}{%
  \printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \setunit{\ptitleaddonpunct}%\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
     \ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@related}%
       and
       test {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reviewof}}%
     }%
     {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
       \usebibmacro{related}}%
     {\printfield{titleaddon}}%
     }%\newcunit\newblock

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paper:Title-Case,
  title   = {Title-Cased Title {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author  = {Author Aaa and Author Bbb},
  year    = {1986},
  volume  = {16},
  pages   = {1929-1943},
  journal = {Journal of Something},
}
@article{paper:Sentence-case,
  title   = {Sentence-cased title {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author  = {Author Ccc and Author Ddd},
  year    = {1987},
  volume  = {17},
  pages   = {1943-1949},
  journal = {Journal of Something Else}
}
@book{book:Title-Case,
  title     = {Title-Cased Book Title {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author    = {Author Eee},
  year      = {1988},
  pages     = {123},
  publisher = {A Good Publisher}
}
@book{book:Sentence-case,
  title     = {Sentence-cased book {ABC} DEF Hij},
  author    = {Author Fff},
  year      = {1989},
  pages     = {567},
  publisher = {Another Good Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{paper:Title-Case}
\autocite{paper:Sentence-case}
\autocite{book:Title-Case}
\autocite{book:Sentence-case}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aaa, Author, and Author Bbb. 1986. “Title-cased title ABC def hij.” Journal of Something 16:1929–1943.]